# How to reach database via another database that has link to that database

Tags: sql, oracle, dblink

[Databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUhOb.png)

Hi, let's use this picture as an example. I want to reach ABASE while on CBASE. I can reach it while on BBASE using

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE@ABASE_LINK
```

I can reach BBASE while on CBASE using

```
SELECT * FROM BBASE.table.
```

But how do i reach ABASE while on CBASE.

If I try

```
SELECT * FROM BBASE.TABLE@ABASE_LINK
```

I get the following error

ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
02019. 00000 -  "connection description for remote database not found"
*Cause:    The referenced database link did not exist.
*Action:   Create the database link before running the SQL statement.
Error at Line: 1 Column: 21

Comment: You must create a dblink of the other database

Comment: Are BBASE and CBASE actually two databases, or two schemas in one database? `SELECT * FROM BBASE.table` suggests the latter, unless you have a synonym hiding a database link.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, they are two schemas in one database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you use `CREATE DATABASE LINK ...` then you are creating a private database  link only for that user; so `CBASE` would not be able to see a private database link belonging to `BBASE`.
- If you use `CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK ...` then you are creating a public database link that all users can use.

You probably have a private database link so it will not be available to another user. Recreate the database link so that it is public and then you can use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE@ABASE_LINK
```